# Disabling the Ubuntu 21.04 "Authentication Required" Pop-Up?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, password, root, authentication

I'd like to disable the GUI "Authentication Required" pop-up on a desktop Ubuntu 21.04 system.

The information I've managed to find generally points to `sudo visudo` and adding a line like `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. However, on Ubuntu 21.04 at least, this only disables the `sudo` password requirement in terminal windows -- the GUI pop-up still appears when a GUI program needs root access.

Is there any way to disable that pop-up?

Thanks!

Comment: Unbelievably annoying pop-up. Do you know if it serves any important purpose? I'm networking my Ubuntu box and running some port-forwarding.